# Show that $f'''(c)=0$ when $f(x)$ has three points where the value of the function is 0

Tags: real-analysis

Let function $f(x)$ be $3$ times differentiable in $[a,b]$. The function has $4$ different points in $[a,b]$ at which the value of a function is $0$. Show that there exists at least one point $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'''(c)=0$.

Unfortunately I managed to get $0$ points in the recent test without any feedback from the professor, so that would be really great if someone could give an helping hand and explain, how the problem is solved.

Comment: Use Roll's MVT three times.

Comment: this is the repeated application of Rolle's theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the points $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 <x_4$. By Rolle's theorem, there are $y_1, y_2, y_3,$ with $x_1 < y_1 < x_2 < y_2 < x_3 < y_3 < x_4$ such that $f'(y_1) = f'(y_2) = f'(y_3) = 0$. Using Rolle's theorem again, this time on $f'$, there are $z_1,z_2$ such that $y_1 < z_1 < y_2 < z_2 < y_3$ such that $f''(z_1) = f''(z_2) = 0.$ Finally, using Rolle's theorem on $f''$, there is $c$ such that $z_1 < c < z_2$ and $f'''(c) = 0$.